# FileNotFound except when getting URL resource with an accent Java

Tags: java, android, url, bitmap

I'm getting a FileNotFoundException when I'm trying to download the file http://tfob.azstarnet.com/images/authors/Alcal%C3%A1_Kathleen_small.jpg. The problem is almost certainly the fact that the URL has an accented character in the string. How can I deal with that?

This is how I'm downloading it.

```
Log.d(TFOB.TAG, "Image src: " + desc.getString("image"));
productURL = new URL (desc.getString("image").trim());
prod = productURL.openConnection();
is = prod.getInputStream(); // Exception gets thrown here
bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
bit = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
```

This is the stack trace:

```
Image src: http://tfob.azstarnet.com/images/authors/Alcalá_Kathleen_small.jpg
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://tfob.azstarnet.com/images/authors/Alcalá_Kathleen_small.jpg
org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1162)
```

Do I have to escape the accent or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

*[URLDecoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLDecoder.html)*

​​​​​​​​​​

​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: I just tried it with "UTF-8" as the encoding. Is that what I should use or would it be considered a different encoding?

Comment: I ended up just doing a .replace("á","%C3%A1") and it works. It's hacky, but I guess it's a bug in android 2.2

Answer (score 2):

Solution (in my case):

In case when the server response code is >= HTTP_BAD_REQUEST (greater than 400), method getInputStream() of class HttpURLConnectionImpl throws
FileNotFoundException (so you cannot open input stream).

Even if this file exist, your object will not give you input stream, because of server response code is >=400 - **change response code on server** or **use another class** to connect.

Fragment of source code:
http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/harmony/luni/internal/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnectionImpl.java.html

```
  867       @Override
  868       public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
  869           if (!doInput) {
  870               throw new ProtocolException(Messages.getString("luni.28")); //$NON-NLS-1$
  871           }
  872
  873           // connect before sending requests
  874           connect();
  875           doRequest();
  876
  ...
  883           if (responseCode >= HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
  884               throw new FileNotFoundException(url.toString());
  885           }
  886
  887           return uis;
  888       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solvede with brutal method:

```
private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String strPhotoUrl) {
    try{    
        String lnk = strPhotoUrl;
            lnk = lnk.replaceAll("à","%C3%A0");
            lnk = lnk.replaceAll("è","%C3%A8");
            lnk = lnk.replaceAll("è","%C3%A9");
            lnk = lnk.replaceAll("ì","%C3%AC");
            lnk = lnk.replaceAll("ò","%C3%B2");
            lnk = lnk.replaceAll("ù","%C3%B9");
            Log.i("Tommy", lnk+"\n");
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(lnk).getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
            return d;
            } catch (Exception e) {
               //System.out.println("Exc=" 2e);
                Log.i("Tommy", strPhotoUrl+"\n");
                Log.i("Tommy", e.toString() + "\n\n");
                return null;
            }
}
```